# Update a label when I change a dropdown selection?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basically I want my label *priceLabel* to automatically update when the user changes their selection on a dropdown list *sizeDropdown*

For example, they select a size from sizeDropdown, this then changes an amount decimal and then converts this decimal into a string and puts it into priceLabel. If the user changes there selection on sizeDropdown it automatically reupdates priceLabel.

This is what I currently have but it doesnt work:

In the HTML

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="sizeDropdown" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="sizeDropdown_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Then in the aspx.cs

Values get Added in one method:

```
sizeDropdown.Items.Add("50g");
sizeDropdown.Items.Add("100g");
```

The in another I try to assign the price:

```
protected void sizeDropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double amount = 0;
    if (sizeDropdown.SelectedItem.Equals("50g"))
    {
        amount = 4.99;
    }
    else if (sizeDropdown.SelectedItem.Equals("100g"))
    {
        amount = 7.99;
    }

    priceLabel.Text = amount.ToString();
}
```

Thanks

EDIT: hank you everyone for the help! I will leave this ehre, and if anyones nterested in ow I fixed it  just converted the selected value to a string then used that which saved a lot of hastle. Cheers!

Comment: Show us the code where you bind the dropdownlist

Comment: Updated the original post :)

Comment: This is the event when selection of dropdown is changed Where you bind sizeDropdown?

Comment: Added more code to the op now

Comment: I added diff approach

Answer (score 2):

Use this in sizeDropdown Tag

```
   AutoPostBack="True"
```

**SelectedItem.Text** in all conditions

```
    if (sizeDropdown.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("50g"))
    {
       amount = 4.99;
    }
```

if you adding the items in page_load event otherwise it is not needed

```
 if(!Page.IsPostBack)
 {
  sizeDropdown.Items.Add("50g");
  sizeDropdown.Items.Add("100g");
 }
```

Comment: Hey you got a Answer?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do two things

- Add  `AutoPostBack="True"` in tag to perform postback which is false by default.
- Bind code in `!Page.IsPostBack`, so that your dropdown do not bind again and loose the selected option.

HTML

```
<asp:DropDownList  ID="sizeDropdown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="sizeDropdown_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Code bhind

```
if( !Page.IsPostBack)
{
   sizeDropdown.Items.Add("50g");
   sizeDropdown.Items.Add("100g");
}
```

Comment: Do you click the joeyButton before changing the dropdown option? You do not need if statement in this function in order to fire selectedIndex change

Answer (score 0):

hey try this i have same issue solve by this....
In desgin add AutoPostBack="True" for dropdownlist.

```
<asp:DropDownList  ID="sizeDropdown" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="sizeDropdown_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

In code behind.....

```
protected void sizeDropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   double amount = 0;
   if (sizeDropdown.SelectedItem.Equals("50g"))
   {
      amount = 4.99;
   }
   else if (sizeDropdown.SelectedItem.Equals("100g"))
    {
       amount = 7.99;
    }
   else if (sizeDropdown.SelectedItem.Equals("150g"))
   {
      amount = 9.99;
   }
      priceLabel.Text = amount.ToString();
}
```

Hope this may be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks, but I get error "Attribute 'SelectedIndexChanged' is not a valid attribute of element 'DropDownList'"

Comment: dont copy paste buddy put "OnSelectedIndexChanged" instead of SelectedIndexChanged. i had updated my answer please check.

Answer (score 0):

**Aspx Code:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="sizeDropdown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            onselectedindexchanged="sizeDropdown_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="4.99">50gms</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="7.99">100g</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Label ID="priceLabel" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

**.Cs Code**

```
 protected void sizeDropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sizeDropdown.SelectedItem.Text != "Select")
        {
            priceLabel.Text = sizeDropdown.SelectedItem.Value;

        }
        else
        {
            priceLabel.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick Solution

Please replace your code with following code.

aspx page :

```
<asp:DropDownList  ID="sizeDropdown" runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="sizeDropdown_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
```

code page:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   sizeDropdown.Items.Add("50g");
   sizeDropdown.Items.Add("100g");
}
```